# Microsoft Graph API Sharepoint $filter error

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to extract information from a sharepoint list using msal and requests. I have been able to pull out the information in a json format, but I want to be able to use the `$filter` with the `lastModifiedDateTime` field to filter the pulls by date.

The format I have been using has followed that of below. I have attempted to use the `%20` for spaces, no '' around the comparison datetime, and other slight alterations.

The error I get is:

> Invalid filter clause: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.string' for operator kind greater than or equal'
> f"{url}sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?l$filter=modifiedDateTime ge '2021-06-02T00:00:00Z'"

Answer (score 0):

Why not usage caml query?
Can you create the query using the **[U2U Caml Query Builder](https://www.u2u.be/software)** program?